# How to align the grid items to the screen if one item is removed-CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, less, css-grid

I have seven items loaded. I am going to write the logic such that if I hide the items, the other items should align to the screen automatically

For example,
if the task is removed(hidden) the  item1, item2, item3, item 4,and the other item should align to the screen and vice versa

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  padding: 77px 88px 0 88px;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  grid-template-columns: 624px repeat(2, 304px);
  grid-template-rows: auto repeat(2, 1fr) fr;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.tasks {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.t1 {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.t2 {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.t3 {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.t4 {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.otherItems {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  grid-row: 3/4;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="task">Task</div>
  <div class="t1">1</div>
  <div class="t2">2</div>
  <div class="t3">3</div>
  <div class="t4">4</div>
  <div class="otheritems">other items</div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: why are you hiding t2 hen you say you need to hide task?

Comment: @Dimava it was just an example that i showed.we can hide even t2 t3 t4 anything but ultimately i need to realign to the screen as shown

Answer (score 1):

Do not set columns and rows to the items, just let the grid place them

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 90px repeat(3, 80px);
  grid-template-rows: auto repeat(2, 1fr) 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.grid-container * {
 background-color: tomato;
 height: 100%;
}

.task {
  grid-row: span 2;
}


.otheritems {
  grid-column: span 4;
  width: 360px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="task">Task</div>
  <div class="t1">1</div>
  <div class="t2">2</div>
  <div class="t3">3</div>
  <div class="t4">4</div>
  <div class="otheritems">other items</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the align-items property on the grid container, to align the items using one of the following values: like
auto.
normal.
start.
end.
center.

Comment: I have used align-item :center and tried other values also It didn't work for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).